Can I connect with the editor on social platforms during manuscript submission or wait until the process is completed?
Suppose that I am an author of a manuscript that was submitted to a journal. During the submission process, I have came across the personal account of the editor handling my manuscript on social platforms such as (Linkedin), do you think it is suitable to send him/her a connection request at that point or wait till the whole submission process is done?

May I ask why you feel the need to connect with a complete stranger over social media? I always find it very odd when complete strangers with no connection to me add me to linkedin. You already have access to this person in their professional capacity, you can send them manuscripts and interact with them accordingly through that venue.

@R1NaNo. I didn't mention anywhere in my question about 'need' to connect to people, besides I specified the platfrom which is profession-oriented and not related to personal life. That's your opinion and I respect that but we can't  generalize the situation, for instance, I might want to have a direct discussion with that person on a professional level and coincidently the scenario I described in my question just happened (You might think oh you can use email! Sure but sometimes a direct message would be more effective and faster than replying an email)

Wait until the editor's conflict of interest -- namely handling your submission -- is resolved. That's just good general etiquette.
